# Javascript function at key value assignment in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to find a solution for the next problem I encountered. I am trying to build a dynamic string by using Amchart3 in my project, and I need to do something like this:

```
return [{
    id: 'Rate',
    alphaField: 'alpha',
    balloonText: function(graphDataItem, graph): String {
      let stringNew = 'smth';
      return stringNew;
    },
}];
```

The problem I encountered is that the function written in the ballonText value isn't triggered (I put a breakpoint to check) and doesn't return anything when calling the function that uses the returned list.

My question is, how could I write a function like

```
key: function(a,b) {
     return a + b;
}
```

in Angular 7, like it is done in Javascript?

Comment: How are you calling that function `balloonText`?

Comment: I am calling that function when hovering on a dot in my chart. Normally it should call and pass "graphDataItem" and "graph" further to the function.

Comment: Read the docs since they are usually very instructive.. The `balloonText` property only takes a string: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/AmGraph/#balloonText

Comment: Now that I looked in there I saw the problem. Looks like I needed to pass "balloonFunction" instead of "ballonText". Now the function works. I assumed wrong that this isn't how you write a function in angular 7. 
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the way you assign the function 'value' to your key `ballonText`. If using es6, which lets you shorthand key/value names, you can assign the function like so:

```js
const es6Assign = {
  id: 'Rate',
  myFunc(str) {
    return str.toUpperCase();
  }
}

// prints out HELLO
console.log('calling es6Assign func: ', es6Assign.myFunc('hello'));
```

If you want to do it the vanilla way, you should name the function even if its the value of a key:

```js
const explicitAssign = {
  id: 'Rate',
  myFunc: function myFunc(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase();
  }
}

// prints out hello
console.log('calling explicitAssign func: ', explicitAssign.myFunc('HELLO'));
```

As to the *why?*; my guess is that even though to *you* the key is the 'name' of the function, to the code, a function that has no name doesn't exist, i.e. `function() { ... }` will return `undefined`. I added the case in the sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecdvq0tk/) so you can see what happens.